# SSIS -- Cannot use local variable 'If' before it is declared

Tags: c#, ssis

I am working in SSIS (BIDS) under SQL Server 2008.  In my control flow, I am testing if a file exists (via a script task) before it moves to the data flow task.  I am having an issue with my If-Then-Else statement in my script task.  Visual Studio is throwing a warning, stating that it "cannot use local variable 'If' before it is declared".  I don't know why this is occurring.  Any suggestions?  Below is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace ST_2f8cf79f6fe0443b9c09c453433a0258.csproj
{
    [System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {

        #region VSTA generated code
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

        public void Main()
        {
            If (File.Exists(CStr(Dts.Variables("PVR_file_path").Value))) Then
                Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Success
            Else
                Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Failure
            End If
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: That looks like a mix of `c#` and `vb.net`. Try using `if (...) { } else { }` (note the lowercase and lack of `Then` and `End If`).

Comment: I made the correction you suggested.  However, the script editor is now throwing 3 more warnings.  The first one is that 'CStr' does not exist in the current context.  The second one is that the non-invocable member 'Variables' cannot be used like a method.  The last one is that 'Results' does not have a definition.

Comment: I've added an answer that hopefully covers your question and your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have used `VB.Net` for your `if` but the rest of the code is in `C#`. Changing your `Main` method to something like this should do the trick:

```
public void Main()
{
    if (File.Exists(Dts.Variables["PVR_file_path"].Value.ToString()))
    {
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
    else
    {
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
    }
}
```

To explain this a little:

- I've changed the `for` loop to C# syntax.
- `Dts.Variables` is a collection so the paranthesis become square brackets. To convert it to a string you can call `ToString()` rather than using `CStr` which doesn't exist in `C#`.
- Finally, I've changed the result to use the `enum` that was defined in the generated code.

Comment: Thank you.  I made this mistake because I'm new to C#.  Many sites online that describe how to do a "file exists" check in SSIS are assuming VB (which is how I got the code).  When I use the script editor in BIDS, I'm in C#.  I don't know why that is, but I'll be sure to be careful moving forward.  Also, there needs to be an (int) before the two ScriptResults.

Comment: Oops.  I just saw that you added the ints.

Comment: Thanks @user3100444 - I've added the casts to the answer. I'm not on a machine where I can run the code so I hadn't tested it.